# Переименовать файл(android)

Tags: android

Задача вроде тривиальная, вот только возникли сложности.

Мне приходит адрес файла в методе `onActivityResult` после чего я его создаю

```
File file = new File(data.getData().getPath());
```

Создание проходит успешно, вопросов нет. Затем я пытаюсь переименовать файл вот таким образом :

```
File file = new File(data.getData().getPath());
File file2 = new File(data.getData().getPath(),"324234235461.txt");
file1.renameTo(file2);
```

Увы, ничего не происходит. У файла остается имя которое было получено во время вызова конструктора `new File(data.getData().getPath());`

Comment: Разрешения стоят на память? (Глупо, но и такое бывает)

Comment: Все возможные разрешения с памятью установлены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А где имя файла `file1`? Зачем брать путь 2 раза?

```
Path path = Paths.get(data.getData().getPath()).getParent());
String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
File from = new File(path, fileName);
File to = new File(path,"324234235461.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```

**UPD**

В конструктор `File` надо передавать папку, где этот файл находится и его имя. Что у вас находится в переменной `path`? Полный путь к файлу? Надо путь к папке (см. код выше)

Comment: Это решение из гугла, пытался указывать без пути а просто имя...тоже не помогло

Comment: Обновил ответ, гляньте

Comment: Не уверен, что `getPafent` вернет путь. Смотрите еще в сторону `getAbsolutePath`